# why ajax display DateTime bad format "/Date(1493818989603)/"?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I wanna send a form to **MVC controller** controller return DateTime 
but display this format **/Date(1493818989603)/**. I have a simple form that it contains(an input and button).

```
    [HttpPost]
    [DynamicCache(VaryByParam = "none")]
    public ActionResult DynamicCache(int duration)
    {
        var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        configuration.AppSettings.Settings["Duration"].Value = duration.ToString();
        configuration.Save();

        System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();

        var timeNow = DateTime.Now;
        return Json(new { result = timeNow });

    }
```

====================================

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group ">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <input type="number" class="form-control form-control input-lg" id="suplyNumber" placeholder="Enter number">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<h1 class="col-lg-offset-5">Result</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="result">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var duration = $("#suplyNumber").val();
            var dataJson = { "duration": duration };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/DynamicCache",
                data: JSON.stringify(dataJson),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#result").html("Result: " + data.result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try this to convert it : // .NET Date/String converter
if (!String.prototype.parseNETDate) {
    String.prototype.parseNETDate = function () {
        if (this.indexOf('-') == -1) {
            return new Date(parseInt(this.slice(6, 19)));
        } else {
            return new Date(parseInt(this.slice(6, 20)));
        }
    };
}

Comment: All you do is var date = data.result.parseNETDate()

Comment: @Steve, I get this error "data.result.parseNETDate is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this as an answer so you can read it properly. The default .NET json serializer returns dates in the format : e.g. /Date(1493818989603)/

If you define a prototype function such as :

```
// .NET Date/String converter
if (!String.prototype.parseNETDate) {
    String.prototype.parseNETDate = function () {
        if (this.indexOf('-') == -1) {
            return new Date(parseInt(this.slice(6, 19)));
        } else {
            return new Date(parseInt(this.slice(6, 20)));
        }
    };
}
```

Then on your object you can do :

```
var dateParsed = data.result.parseNETDate();
```

You **must** define the function before calling this.

Comment: It looks correct. Try alert(typeof(data.result)); It should say "string". That's how the prototype works, it expects it to be a string.

Comment: In the console doing "/Date(1493818989603)/".parseNETDate() gives me 
Wed May 03 2017 14:43:09 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time).

Comment: I use alert(typeof(data.result) it's string but I got error this line**var date = data.result.parseNetDate(); ** Uncaught TypeError: data.result.parseNetDate is not a function

Comment: Ah. I looked at your fiddle again and you've wrapped parseNETDate() in a function (which is why it isn't working). You can declare it as global. See : https://jsfiddle.net/3jdcn8ee/1/ for a corrected one.